# What is the correct format for final block in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex for decryption?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I have implemented a simple AES-256-GCM encryption and decryption for learning purposes. While testing my code if I enter strings lengths multiples of 6 then I get the correct output but for other cases the decrypted data has some garbage characters appended to it.

```
Case1:
Enter string: abcdef
Enter key: sdasdasdsa
-^%�
abcdef
6

Case2:
Enter string: abcdefghi
Enter key: sadsadsad
\h�,�[�
abcdefghi�\�
-1
```

Now I read on the https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptFinal_ex.html that

```
EVP_DecryptFinal() will return an error code if padding is enabled and the
final block is not correctly formatted.
```

But since padding is enabled by default in this case I am guessing that the problem is with the correct formatting of the final block. I have attached my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

void handleErrors()
{
    printf("Some error occured\n");
}

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *aad,
    int aad_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned char *tag)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len, ciphertext_len=0;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the encryption operation. */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Set IV length if default 12 bytes (96 bits) is not appropriate */
    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise key and IV */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide any AAD data. This can be called zero or more times as
     * required
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len+= len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Normally ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage, but this does not occur in GCM mode
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Get the tag */
    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}


int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *aad,
    int aad_len, unsigned char *tag, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len, plaintext_len=0, ret;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) 
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Set IV length. Not necessary if this is 12 bytes (96 bits) */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
        handleErrors();

    /* Initialise key and IV */
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide any AAD data. This can be called zero or more times as
     * required
     */
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, aad, aad_len))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len+= len;

    /* Set expected tag value. Works in OpenSSL 1.0.1d and later */
    if(!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, tag))
        handleErrors();

    /* Finalise the decryption. A positive return value indicates success,
     * anything else is a failure - the plaintext is not trustworthy.
     */
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len);

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    if(ret > 0)
    {
        /* Success */
        plaintext_len += len;
        return plaintext_len;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Verify failed */
        return -1;
    }
}


int main (void)
{
    unsigned char str[1024],key[10],ciphertext[1024+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH],tag[100],pt[1024];
    unsigned char iv[]="1234567890abcdef";
    unsigned char aad[]="1234567890123456";
    int k;
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%s",key);

    encrypt(str, strlen(str), aad, strlen(aad), key, iv, ciphertext, tag);
    printf("%s\n",ciphertext);
    k = decrypt(ciphertext, strlen(ciphertext), aad, strlen(aad), tag, key, iv, pt);
    printf("%s\n%d\n",pt,k);
}
```

Comment: Always use a language tag, or your code highlighting does not work and you will get less views (although that may have been beneficial in this case).

Comment: Hi @bawejakunal. You received two good answers below, would you consider accepting one? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the one you found most helpful. This marks the question as resolved, and awards a few extra points to that helper for their effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example you are defining your key, IV data to be strings. A key and IV should never consist of a string as they do not contain any possible byte. This is required to maximize the amount of security; currently you are limiting the amount of possible keys. Keys should be generated by a function whose output is indistinguishable from random.

You should use a Password Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) such as PBKDF2 to create a key from a password. The IV should be random and send with the ciphertext. The IV and key should be statically sized, the IV being 16 bytes and the key 16, 24 or 32 bytes.

To test however you could use simple array initialization (32 bytes for the key as you are using AES-256):

```
unsigned char key[32] = { 0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,
                          0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,
                          0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,
                          0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00 };
unsigned char iv[16] = { 0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,
                         0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00 };
```

or you could allocate X bytes of memory and fill it with a value of course, as long as you give the function the correct size.

You need to replace all occurrences of `strlen()` with `sizeof()`, except for `plaintext` and `ciphertext`. In the former you are actually encrypting a string, so `strlen` makes sense. In the latter you need to use the result of the `encrypt` operation. The ciphertext is contained within a buffer of the length (correctly) returned by your encryption method.

In the end modern ciphers operate *on bytes* instead of *characters*, so you need to provide the size in bytes for all input. This kind of issue is present for any language that treats bytes and characters using the same primitive type (`char` for the C-language of course). It also tends to hide encoding/decoding issues (e.g. with regards to UTF-8).

If you want to handle unknown lengths then you have to call `EVP_EncryptUpdate` or `EVP_DecryptUpdate` multiple times, keeping score on how many bytes are returned (as you are doing now). Then at the end of the input you simply call the update method a final time and then call `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` or `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex`. In that case you should of course refactor your method into an *init/update/final* part and use some buffer for the input and output.

Comment: Also upvoted jww but I think his answer did not fully capture the underlying character vs binary issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for your insights :) Really helpful, I have just begun with cryptography. Could you please elaborate on the importance of aad too please ? Thanks again!!

Comment: AAD is important *if* you have data that needs to be protected outside the ciphertext. IMHO it's mostly useful if you have for instance format descriptors, protocol versions etc. that you need to protect. With GCM (and most authenticated ciphers) the IV is already protected though. If it is a string or binary is of course dependent on the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

> `decrypt(ciphertext, strlen(ciphertext), aad, strlen(aad), tag, key, iv, pt);`

`decrypt(ciphertext, strlen(ciphertext), ...` is wrong. There could be an embedded NULL in the cipher text, in which case it will be truncated. In your case, additional characters are being fed to the `decrypt` function. Its hard to say how many - its until `strlen` happen to run into a NULL in memory.

You need to capture the return value of `encrypt` and `decrpyt` to set various length's properly:

```
int x;
...

x = encrypt(str, strlen(str), aad, strlen(aad), key, iv, ciphertext, tag);
...

x = decrypt(ciphertext, x, aad, strlen(aad), tag, key, iv, pt);
...
```

You might have the same problem for `aad, strlen(aad)`, but I don't think it has revealed itself yet.

---

> What is the correct format for final block in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex for decryption?

To get back to the titular question: there is none. Your problem lies elsewhere.

---

You probably have an overflow in the `unsigned char *plaintext` buffer used in the `decrypt` function. You're not passing in a length, so `decrypt` happily writes beyond the length of it...

Comment: Ok I get your point of capturing the lengths of encrypted string(ciphertext) in `variable x` and using that during decryption. Thanks for pointing that out, though I still am not able to understand why `strlen(aad)` will create a problem ?

Also I figured out the reason why `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` returned an error code, that's because the size of `pt` should have been 1056, not 1024 i.e atleast input length + block size.

Comment: Another doubt that just cropped up into my mind, what if we have to decrypt a ciphertext of unknown length, then how to handle that ?